# Regex to match [[Wikipedia:Manual of Style#Links|]] # in java

Tags: java, xml, regex, parsing, url

I have been trying to match the following string -

```
String temp = "[[Wikipedia:Manual of Style#Links|]]" ;
```

with the regex

```
boolean a = temp.matches("\\[\\[Wikipedia:[a-zA-Z_0-9]*#[a-zA-Z_0-9]*\\|\\]\\]");

"\\[\\[Wikipedia:(.*?)#(.*?)\\|\\]\\]"

"\\[\\[Wikipedia:(.*)*#(.+)*\\|\\]\\]"

"\\[\\[(.*?)#(.*?)\\|\\]\\]"
```

But none of them are giving any positive matches.

Comment: Might wanna try: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/ see if it helps

Comment: Are the links embedded in a larger text?

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is correct? The paren should be after the double quote and before the semicolon, and your second regex should work.

Comment: @Jerry Yes, you caught that. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String temp = "[[Wikipedia:Manual of Style#Links|]]";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[Wikipedia:([\\w ]+)#([\\w ]+)\\|\\]\\]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);

    if(matcher.find()) {            
        System.out.println("Manual of Style: " + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("links : " + matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

or

```
temp.matches("\\[\\[Wikipedia:([\\w ]+)#([\\w ]+)\\|\\]\\]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight away I can see a problem: you are using a character class without a space to match input with spaces.

Try this:

```
boolean a = temp.matches("\\[\\[Wikipedia:[\\w ]*#[\\w ]+\\|\\]\\]");
```

Note that `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` can be replaced by `[\w]` (but would include letters/numbers from all languages, which should be fine)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a space to your custom character class:

```
String temp = "[[Wikipedia:Manual of Style#Links|]]" ;
temp.matches("\\[\\[Wikipedia:[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]*#[a-zA-Z_0-9]*\\|\\]\\]");  //true
```